# Using partition with volatile tables?

Tags: teradata

This is **Teradata**

I have a multiset volatile table

I tried to use the following:

```
SELECT 
col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY col1
ORDER BY col2) AS row
FROM mytable
) 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Why do I get `No import parameters ( ?, ?? , ?B or ?C ) found in this query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not your actual query, `row` is a keyword and the alias for the Derived Table is missing.

Nevertheless the error is easy to explan as it's independent of any query: You're using SQL Assistant and clicked somehow on the Import Data icon. Simply uncheck it in the File menu.